# Using Materialized View vs Table when data generated in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, view

As a very naive example, let's say I create a table with some generated data, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE x AS (SELECT 1 AS id...)
```

Or, do the same thing via a Materialized View:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW y AS (SELECT 1 AS id...)
```

What would be the differences between these two table-like object creations, since a MV is usually used as a logical "view" of upstream "physical" tables. Are there limitations on the MV here that a normal table does not have or are they the same for the most part?

Note: I am tagging this as both Postgres and SQLServer since both contain materialized views and this question applies to both (and I'm using both to test), though the above syntax for creating a MV is from Postgres and MsSQL is a bit different.

Comment: I think that you should read here, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html, for a full list of changes for Postgresql. Basically, with the materialized view you cannot have direct update of the information, you have to request for it specifically.

Comment: In SQL Server, a materialized (indexed) view is maintained in real time as the underlying data changes. The limitations are related to query constructs (e.g. no out joins) and the first index on the view must be clustered and unique.